# Boundedness of composition of an inverse of an elliptic differential operator with a differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a Lipschitz domain. Let $A$ be a linear second-order differential operator, not necessarily self-adjoint. Let $\Omega$ and the coefficients of $A$ satisfy assumptions (e.g. "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans, Section 6.3.2), such that one gets that the differential equation
\begin{align*}
A u &= f \text{ in } \Omega, \\
u(x) &= 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega
\end{align*}
gives a solution $u \in H^2$ for any $f \in L^2$, i.e., $A^{-1}$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^2$ to $H^2$.

Consider the operator $B = A^{-1} D^\alpha$ for $\alpha$ being an order two multi-index and $D^\alpha$ being the according differential operator. Can one show that the operator $B$ is bounded from $L^2$ to $L^2$, meaning that it is bounded for a dense subset? I know that it is true for $D^{\alpha} A^{-1}$, but I am not sure about this case. If it is not true, can one find a counter-example?

Comment: $D^{\alpha}$ isn’t even defined on all of $L^2$, so you can’t get a bounded operator.

Comment: That isn't really true: $D^\alpha$ could be interpreted as a mapping into $H^{-2}$, in which case then the estimate becomes one about estimates on the elliptic equation in negative Sobolev spaces. You can obtain such estimates via duality arguments so long as you assume sufficient regularity of the data.

Comment: I see. I have not found any references that discuss regularity theory for elliptic equations in negative Sobolev spaces. Do you know any reference?

Comment: @peek-a-boo: That is a good point. A trick that one can always use, is to show boundedness on a dense subset, e.g. $C^\infty$, in which case $D^\alpha$ is well-defined. Then, one can argue that there is a bounded unique extension to $L^2$.

Comment: Differential operators are not bounded in the $L^2\to L^2$ norms, they are however bounded in the Sobolev norms, hence my previous comment. But ok the comment above mentions duality to apply elliptic estimates in the negative Sobolev case, which I’ve not thought about/worked out but it seems interesting.

Comment: Yes, the differential operator is unbounded in that sense, but the composition does not necessarily have to be.